# does appengine have a pointer to the latest deployed application

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to test my thick client against my RESTful appengine application. I regularly increment the appengine version number so I need to keep updating my test config. Is there the equivalent of `http://latest.application.appspot.com` that I could point my config too?

Thanks

Comment: you mean for your default version or for a secondary dev version?

Comment: it's for the secondary dev version, the default version is pointed to by my website name.

Comment: so you are incrementing the dev versions number and you want to access the latest deployed dev version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this. Versions aren't sequenced - they're all entirely distinct deploys, only one of which is set as the default.

Comment: Thanks for that Nick.  Reading over the answers it seems like named versions e.g 'debug' 'test' and 'prod' rather than  numbered versions would be a better fit.

Comment: @directedbit I agree, and I try to use named versions in any examples I write - a lot of people don't even know names are permissible!

Answer (score 3):

Skirting around your question, but in my head, I've stopped thinking of the "version" in the typical software release version (which like you, I started out thinking), but rather, it's "a different application using the same datastore".

I found out the software release version (1.0, 1.1, 1.2 etc) doesn't make much sense because 1) I don't tend to use older versions 2) my main usage would be to regression test, but this doesn't work well, because it's quite possible for a change in your model in v1.1 to break the code in v1.0.

The versions feature comes in hand to have different functional versions.  For example, maybe the default application.appspot.com runs production level code, but debug.application.appspot.com has more logging enabled.  Perhaps a third version has administrator functionality enabled, etc.

Answer (score 2):

What you are likely looking for is the `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` environment variable. It stores the deployment revision as dot-separated string: `version_name.deployment_revision`, e.g. `staging.12345678910111213141516`. You could just use it directly in your config:

```
import os
API_VERSION = os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'].split('.')[1]
```